# C# code to run weka classifier

Tags: c#, classification, weka, ikvm

I am using C# and have included IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll and am using the following Java code:

```
public static void cvdTest()
{

    weka.core.Instances data = new weka.core.Instances(new java.io.FileReader("test.arff"));
    data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);

    weka.classifiers.Classifier cls = new weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes();

    int runs = 1;
    int folds = 10;

    // perform cross-validation
    for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
      // randomize data
      int seed = i + 1;
      java.util.Random rand = new java.util.Random(seed);
      weka.core.Instances randData = new weka.core.Instances(data);
      randData.randomize(rand);
      if (randData.classAttribute().isNominal())
        randData.stratify(folds);

      weka.classifiers.Evaluation eval = new weka.classifiers.Evaluation(randData);
      for (int n = 0; n < folds; n++) {
        weka.core.Instances train = randData.trainCV(folds, n);
        weka.core.Instances test = randData.testCV(folds, n);
        // build and evaluate classifier
        weka.classifiers.Classifier clsCopy = weka.classifiers.Classifier.makeCopy(cls);
        clsCopy.buildClassifier(train);
        eval.evaluateModel(clsCopy, test);
      }
```

But i am getting th following error:

> The type initializer for 'java.io.File' threw an exception.

On the line:

```
weka.core.Instances data = new weka.core.Instances(new java.io.FileReader("test.arff"));
```

Comment: I have edited my question to a rather specific one. Could I get some help now??

Comment: Not my specific area of expertise, but can you find out what the exception was (through the debugger maybe?)

Comment: It is a System.TypeInitializationException

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you did not skip the conversion of the weka.jar to weka.dll using Ikvm before adding it as a reference to your C# project
Conversion from Java to a .NET dll
With that out of the way, the first thing you will want to do is to convert the Weka .jar file into a .NET dll. To do this, we will use ikvmc, which is the IKVM static compiler.
On the console, go to the directory which contains weka.jar, and type:

> ikvmc -target:library weka.jar

The -target:library call causes ikvmc to create a .dll library instead of an executable.

Note that the IKVM tutorial tells you that you should add -reference:/usr/lib/IKVM.GNU.Classpath.dll(or appropriate path) to the above command, it tells IKVM where to find the GNU Classpath library. However, IKVM.GNU.Classpath.dll Is no longer included in the download package, and is from very old versions of IKVM. When Sun open sources Java, it got replaced by the IKVM.OpenJDK.*.dll files.

You should now have a file called "weka.dll", which is a .NET version of the entire weka API. That's exactly what you need!

Answer (score 1):

Possible, you didn't add required dll. Try to add to the References next dlls: IKVM.Runtime.dll and IKVM.OpenJDK.Text.dll.
Also, "Often an exception wraps the original exception. In such cases, the InnerException property holds information about the original exception."
So to find out the reason of exception go to ViewDetail and look there Inner Exception (it can be nested, so go down while not found the sought-for).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource source = 
  new weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource(filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

including a reference to IKVM.OpenJDK.XML.Parse.dll solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that references includes this list:

[image]